# contents of a Editable text field does not display in lotus notes view

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus, lotus-formula

I have mapped a editable text field in the view, But it is not visible when previewed,
"Product Number" is the field name.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the field really stored in the documents or did you add it AFTER the documents where created and now you need to refresh them to have the field? Please check document properties, if Item "ProductNumber" is present. And IF it is present, then check, if it sais "Field Flags: SUMMARY" in there. A "non"- SUMMARY- field can also not be displayed in a view.

Comment: Actually, Previously field type "is Rich Text field" now it is changed to "Text".
Now for newly created documents "Product number" is visible in view and If I look into old documents properties still the type of product number is Rich Text and Field Flags doesn't have summary

Comment: Yes, that is normal: changing the design of a form does NOT change documents that have already been created with this form... There is only a very loose connection between Design and Data.... You could try to Write an agent (Trigger: None) with the following command: @Command( [ToolsRefreshSelectedDocs] ), then select the old documents and run the agent. That should change the type of the fields in existing documents.